# OneSignal Android notification without SDK imlementation

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am using own solution for Android, iOS and Windows Phone push notifications based on [rs/pushd](https://github.com/rs/pushd) service and everything works well.

I've  tried switch from own solution to OneSignal platform with my database with device tokens. There is no problem to send a push notification from OneSignal interface to my iPhone without any change in iOS app.

When I try to send push notification to my Android devices - push notification will send with OneSignal's state "Delivered (100%)" but notification is not shown on any of my devices. Same configurations and device token work on the pushd service. Configuration seems ok, because OneSignal recognize invalidated device tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android the code in the app handles the parsing and displaying of the notification, where on iOS the OS itself does this without waking the app.

It is recommend to use the OneSignal SDK especially for Android as it uses it's own GCM/FCM payload format to support all the features it offers.

The OneSignal GCM/FCM payload format isn't part of the documentation however it can be found as part of the project's unit tests below.

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/3.3.0/OneSignalSDK/app/src/test/java/com/test/onesignal/GenerateNotificationRunner.java#L435

Comment: Yes, problem is in the different payload structure. [rs/pushd](https://github.com/rs/pushd) uses `notification.message` for notification content, OneSignal uses `notification.body`. 

In my case, there is no problem to update an application, but I have thousand app installations and it is impossible to deliver the update to the entire user base. This is the reason why I can't use OneSingal for Android devices now. 

In OneSignal interface, there is possibility to add additional data. Are you planning to add additional data into notification payload?

Comment: OneSignal uses `alert` on the root of the payload for the message body. If your current apps omit the OneSignal payload format then I recommend the following: Import your devices into OneSignal then remove your old GCM/FCM code/SDK and add the OneSignal SDK. You can then start sending notification from OneSignal and users will get the notification if they have your updated version. Keep sending notifications from your old system for users who haven't updated. The OneSignal SDK omits other payload formats so you don't need to worry about double notifications when sending from your old provider.